# Git is "stuck" on another user when try to push my repo

Tags: git, github

Few days ago, i've tried to log another git accoount through the terminal, and regret it, and returned back to my original user.

For some reason, the git "remembers" the another account...

```
remote: Permission to guy490/TravelMatch.git denied to yanaanael.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/guy490/TravelMatch.git/': The requested URL returned 
error: 403
```

"yanaanael" is the another account i've tried to log in few days ago, and now when i'm trying to push my repo and its remember "yanaanael" for some reason.

when I run `git config --list`, this is the result:

```
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
http.sslbackend=openssl
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
credential.helper=manager
user.email=guy8824@gmail.com
user.name=guy490
credential.helper=cache
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/guy490/TravelMatch.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
remote.heroku.url=https://git.heroku.com/travel-match-project.git
remote.heroku.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
user.name=Guy Cohen
user.email=guy8824@gmail.com
credential.helper=store
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one more place to find the credentials.

go to:

**Control Panel -> Credential Manager -> Windows Credentials -> Generic Credentials.**

Comment: Note that this is specific to Windows, but not specific to Git itself: it's a generic Windows thing.